# WiFi connection issues when BLE scan always on

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth, android-ble

I'm currently scanning BLE devices continuosly and undefenetily, but I noticed that my Samsung J1 loose wifi connections, and any atempt to reconect gives "Authentication Error":"Password incorrect". Stoping BLE scan gives access to the wifi networks again (without reentering password).

Theres know issues on that behaviour?

PS: My current Scanner has filters and currently the device just lost 50% battery in 14 hours (including itself running with screen of)

Logcat from system when the event happens: (Afterwards looks like only applications reporting errors cause of internet)

02-09 11:38:54.246 19629-19663/? D/ScanRecord: first manudata for manu ID
02-09 11:38:54.246 19629-19663/? D/BtGatt.GattService: result: ScanResult{mDevice=FC:8F:90:27:18:38, mScanRecord=ScanRecord [mAdvertiseFlags=-1, mServiceUuids=null, mManufacturerSpecificData={117=[66, 4, 1, -128, 0, -4, -113, -112, 39, 24, 56, -2, -113, -112, 39, 24, 55, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]}, mServiceData={}, mTxPowerLevel=-2147483648, mDeviceName=null], mRssi=-91, mTimestampNanos=90987161943833}
02-09 11:38:54.246 19629-19663/? D/BtGatt.GattService: filter: BluetoothLeScanFilter [mDeviceName=null, mDeviceAddress=null, mUuid=0000feaa-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb, mUuidMask=null, mServiceDataUuid=null, mServiceData=null, mServiceDataMask=null, mManufacturerId=-1, mManufacturerData=null, mManufacturerDataMask=null]
02-09 11:38:54.356 19629-19640/? D/BtGatt.GattService: stopScan() - queue size =1
02-09 11:38:54.356 19629-20084/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager: stop scan
02-09 11:38:54.356 19629-20103/? D/BtGatt.GattService: unregisterClient() - clientIf=6
02-09 11:38:54.356 19629-20084/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager: configureRegularScanParams() - queue=0
02-09 11:38:54.356 19629-20084/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager: configureRegularScanParams() - ScanSetting Scan mode=-2147483648 mLastConfiguredScanSetting=2
02-09 11:38:54.356 19629-20084/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager: configureRegularScanParams() - queue emtpy, scan stopped
02-09 11:38:54.356 19629-20094/? D/bluedroid-mrvl: bt_vnd_mrvl_if_op(L95): opcode = 7
02-09 11:38:54.366 19629-20094/? D/bluedroid-mrvl: bt_vnd_mrvl_if_op(L95): opcode = 7
02-09 11:38:54.366 19629-20094/? D/bluedroid-mrvl: bt_vnd_mrvl_if_op(L95): opcode = 7
02-09 11:38:55.096 2414-2898/? D/Netd: Iface wlan0 link down
02-09 11:38:55.096 2839-2857/? D/BatteryService: !@BatteryListener : batteryPropertiesChanged!
02-09 11:38:55.096 2839-2857/? D/BatteryService: level:97, scale:100, status:2, health:2, present:true, voltage: 4271, temperature: 320, technology: Li-ion, AC powered:false, USB powered:true, POGO powered:false, Wireless powered:false, icon:17303201, invalid charger:0
02-09 11:38:55.096 2839-2857/? D/BatteryService: online:4, current avg:0, charge type:1, power sharing:false, high voltage charger:false, capacity:190000, current_now:80
02-09 11:38:55.106 2839-2931/? D/Tethering: interfaceLinkStateChanged wlan0, false
02-09 11:38:55.106 2839-2839/? D/BatteryService: Sending ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED.
02-09 11:38:55.106 2839-2931/? D/Tethering: interfaceStatusChanged wlan0, false
02-09 11:38:55.106 2414-2898/? D/Netd: Iface wlan0 link down
02-09 11:38:55.106 20063-20063/? I/wpa_supplicant: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=C0.85.28 reason=3
02-09 11:38:55.106 20063-20063/? I/wpa_supplicant: wlan0: Setting scan request: 0 sec 500000 usec
02-09 11:38:55.106 2839-3135/? D/Tethering: InitialState.processMessage what=4
02-09 11:38:55.106 20063-20063/? I/wpa_supplicant: wlan0: State: COMPLETED -> DISCONNECTED
02-09 11:38:55.106 20063-20063/? I/wpa_supplicant: CTRL-EVENT-STATE-CHANGE id=13 state=0 BSSID=C0.85.28 SSID=494E41434C4956452032
02-09 11:38:55.106 2839-3135/? D/Tethering: Get OMC_SalesCode failed
02-09 11:38:55.106 2839-3131/? E/WifiConfigStore: setLastSelectedConfiguration -1
02-09 11:38:55.106 2839-2931/? D/Tethering: interfaceLinkStateChanged wlan0, false
02-09 11:38:55.106 2839-2931/? D/Tethering: interfaceStatusChanged wlan0, false
02-09 11:38:55.116 2839-3135/? E/Tethering: No numeric data
02-09 11:38:55.116 3214-3214/? D/KeyguardUpdateMonitor: received broadcast android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED
02-09 11:38:55.116 3214-3214/? D/KeyguardUpdateMonitor: handleBatteryUpdate
02-09 11:38:55.116 19629-19629/? V/HeadsetService: HeadsetService - Received Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED
02-09 11:38:55.116 19629-20085/? D/HeadsetStateMachine: Disconnected process message: 10
02-09 11:38:55.126 3360-3360/? D/BroadcastReceiver 電池レベル:  LEVEL　　97 % 
02-09 11:38:55.126 3360-3360/? D/BroadcastReceiver 電圧:  VOLT　　4271 mv 
02-09 11:38:55.126 3360-3360/? D/BroadcastReceiver 温度:  TEMP　　320 ℃ 
02-09 11:38:55.126 3360-3360/? D/BroadcastReceiver 接続:  Plugged　　2
02-09 11:38:55.126 29974-29974/? D/WidgetProviderAssistiveLight: onReceive() PLUG:2 / STATUS:2 / LEVEL:97
02-09 11:38:55.126 29974-29974/? D/WidgetProviderAssistiveLight: onReceive() : cancel Timer
02-09 11:38:55.126 2839-3135/? D/Tethering: sendTetherStateChangedBroadcast 0, 0, 0
02-09 11:38:55.126 2839-3135/? D/Tethering: clearTetheredNotification()
02-09 11:38:55.126 3214-3214/? D/BatteryMeterView: ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED : level:97 status:2 health:2
02-09 11:38:55.126 3214-3214/? D/BatteryMeterView: ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED : level:97 status:2 health:2
02-09 11:38:55.126 3214-3214/? D/BatteryMeterView: ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED : level:97 status:2 health:2
02-09 11:38:55.136 2839-3131/? E/WifiConfigStore: saveWifiConfigBSSID Setting BSSID for "INACLIVE 2"WPA_PSK to any
02-09 11:38:55.136 3214-3214/? D/HotspotTile: onReceive : android.net.conn.TETHER_STATE_CHANGED
02-09 11:38:55.136 3214-3214/? D/HotspotTile: updateTetherState():false, false
02-09 11:38:55.136 2839-3128/? V/NetworkStats: performPollLocked(flags=0x1)
02-09 11:38:55.136 2839-3128/? D/NetworkStatsFactory: UpdateStatsForKnox updated
02-09 11:38:55.136 2839-3128/? D/NetworkStatsFactory: UpdateStatsForKnox main else ---
02-09 11:38:55.136 2839-2839/? D/WifiNotificationController: SHOW_NOTI_MESSAGE : 12, visible : false, ssid : "INACLIVE 2"
02-09 11:38:55.136 2839-2839/? D/WifiNotificationController: SHOW_NOTI_MESSAGE : 12, visible : false, ssid : "INACLIVE 2", targetSSID : "INACLIVE 2", netId : -1, titleType : -1
02-09 11:38:55.136 2839-2839/? D/WifiNotificationController: showCaptivePortalSignInNotification with ssid/visible:"INACLIVE 2"/false
02-09 11:38:55.136 2839-2915/? E/ActivityManager: checkUser: useridlist=null, currentuser=0
02-09 11:38:55.136 2839-2915/? E/ActivityManager: checkUser: useridlist=null, currentuser=0
02-09 11:38:55.136 2839-2915/? E/ActivityManager: checkUser: useridlist=null, currentuser=0
02-09 11:38:55.136 2839-2915/? E/ActivityManager: checkUser: useridlist=null, currentuser=0
02-09 11:38:55.146 2839-3128/? V/NetworkStats: performPollLocked() took 10ms
02-09 11:38:55.146 2839-3130/? D/WifiP2pService: InactiveState{ what=143375 }
02-09 11:38:55.146 2839-3130/? D/WifiP2pService: P2pEnabledState{ what=143375 }
02-09 11:38:55.146 20063-20063/? I/wpa_supplicant: the nl80211 driver cmd is BTCOEXMODE 2
02-09 11:38:55.156 32697-32697/? E/Zygote: no v2
02-09 11:38:55.156 32697-32697/? I/SELinux: Function: selinux_compare_spd_ram, SPD-policy is existed. and_ver=SEPF_SM-J110M_5.1.1 ver=48
02-09 11:38:55.156 2839-2915/? I/ActivityManager: Start proc 32697:com.android.settings/1000 for broadcast-2 com.android.settings/.wifi.WifiStatusReceiver
02-09 11:38:55.156 2414-2904/? D/CommandListener: Clearing all IP addresses on wlan0
02-09 11:38:55.166 32697-32697/? I/SELinux: Function: selinux_compare_spd_ram , priority [1] , priority version is VE=SEPF_SM-J110M_5.1.1_0048
02-09 11:38:55.166 3746-29513/? V/NativeCrypto: Read error: ssl=0xab98f800: I/O error during system call, Connection timed out
02-09 11:38:55.166 3214-3214/? D/StatusBar.MSimNetworkController: getUpdateDataNetType(): 0
02-09 11:38:55.166 3214-3214/? D/StatusBar.MSimNetworkController: updateDataNetType sub = 0 mDataNetType = 0
02-09 11:38:55.166 3214-3214/? E/StatusBar.MSimNetworkController: updateDataNetType NETWORK_TYPE_UNKNOWN
02-09 11:38:55.166 3214-3214/? D/StatusBar.MSimNetworkController: Nothing final, mRoamingIconId = 0 phoneId : 0
02-09 11:38:55.166 3214-3214/? D/StatusBar.MSimNetworkController: updateZTMDataNetType()
02-09 11:38:55.166 3746-29513/? V/NativeCrypto: SSL shutdown failed: ssl=0xab98f800: I/O error during system call, Broken pipe
02-09 11:38:55.166 3214-3214/? D/StatusBar.MSimNetworkController: updateDataIcon mDataNetType= 0
02-09 11:38:55.176 2839-3134/? E/ConnectivityService: updateNetworkInfo()
02-09 11:38:55.176 2839-3134/? D/ConnectivityService: NetworkAgentInfo [WIFI () - 512] EVENT_NETWORK_INFO_CHANGED, going from CONNECTED to DISCONNECTED, reason = null, [ Transports: WIFI Capabilities: INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED&NOT_VPN LinkUpBandwidth>=1048576Kbps LinkDnBandwidth>=1048576Kbps]
02-09 11:38:55.176 2839-3134/? E/ConnectivityService: updateNetworkInfo()
02-09 11:38:55.176 2839-3134/? D/ConnectivityService: NetworkAgentInfo [WIFI () - 512] got DISCONNECTED, was satisfying 2
02-09 11:38:55.176 32697-32697/? E/SELinux: [DEBUG] get_category: variable seinfo: platform sensitivity: NULL, cateogry: NULL
02-09 11:38:55.176 3214-3214/? D/StatusBar.MSimNetworkController: updateDataIcon phoneId =0 dataSub =0
02-09 11:38:55.176 2839-3131/? E/WifiConfigStore: saveWifiConfigBSSID Setting BSSID for "INACLIVE 2"WPA_PSK to any
02-09 11:38:55.176 3214-3214/? D/StatusBar.MSimNetworkController: updateDataIcon( 0 )  GSM :  mMSimState= ABSENT mDataNetType= 0
02-09 11:38:55.176 2839-2839/? I/WifiTrafficPoller: evaluateTrafficStatsPolling
02-09 11:38:55.176 3214-3214/? D/StatusBar.MSimNetworkController: updateDataIcon no sim
02-09 11:38:55.176 3746-29513/? E/GCM: Wifi connection closed with errorCode 20
02-09 11:38:55.176 2839-29229/? D/NetworkMonitor/NetworkAgentInfo [WIFI () - 512]: ValidatedState{ when=0 what=532488 arg1=10006 target=com.android.internal.util.StateMachine$SmHandler }
02-09 11:38:55.176 2839-29229/? D/NetworkMonitor/NetworkAgentInfo [WIFI () - 512]: DefaultState{ when=0 what=532488 arg1=10006 target=com.android.internal.util.StateMachine$SmHandler }
02-09 11:38:55.176 2839-29229/? D/NetworkMonitor/NetworkAgentInfo [WIFI () - 512]: Forcing reevaluation
02-09 11:38:55.176 2839-29229/? D/NetworkMonitor/NetworkAgentInfo [WIFI () - 512]: EvaluatingState{ when=0 what=532486 arg1=2 target=com.android.internal.util.StateMachine$SmHandler }
02-09 11:38:55.176 2839-29229/? D/NetworkMonitor/NetworkAgentInfo [WIFI () - 512]: Checking http://connectivitycheck.android.com/generate_204 on 
02-09 11:38:55.176 2839-29229/? I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
02-09 11:38:55.186 3214-3214/? D/StatusBar.MSimNetworkController: updateDataIcon when mMSimDataConnected[0] =false mMSimMobileActivityIconId[0] = 0
02-09 11:38:55.186 2839-2935/? D/WifiDisplayController: WifiP2pReceiver::onReceive(): action=android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE
02-09 11:38:55.186 2839-3131/? E/WifiStateMachine: WifiStateMachine: Leaving Connected state
02-09 11:38:55.186 20063-20063/? I/wpa_supplicant: reset timer : RESET_TIMER 0
02-09 11:38:55.186 20063-20063/? I/wpa_supplicant: P2P: Current p2p state = IDLE
02-09 11:38:55.186 20063-20063/? I/wpa_supplicant: wlan0: State: DISCONNECTED -> SCANNING
02-09 11:38:55.186 20063-20063/? I/wpa_supplicant: CTRL-EVENT-STATE-CHANGE id=-1 state=3 BSSID=00.00.00 SSID=
02-09 11:38:55.186 20063-20063/? I/wpa_supplicant: Scan requested (ret=-11) - scan timeout 30 seconds
02-09 11:38:55.196 2839-3131/? D/SecContentProvider2: uri = 20 selection = getPromptCredentialsEnabled
02-09 11:38:55.196 2839-3131/? D/SecContentProvider2: mCursor = null
02-09 11:38:55.196 3214-3214/? D/STATUSBAR-WifiQuickSettingButton: onWifiSignalChanged enabled=true enabledDesc:"INACLIVE 2"
02-09 11:38:55.196 3214-3214/? D/StatusBar.MSimNetworkController: refreshViews connected={ wifi } phoneId = 0 level=4 mMSimcombinedSignalIconId=0x7f0202d4/com.android.systemui:drawable/stat_sys_wifi_signal_4 mMSimcombinedActivityIconId=0x7f0202a8 mAirplaneMode=false mMSimDataActivity=0 mMSimPhoneSignalIconId=0x7f020293/com.android.systemui:drawable/stat_sys_signal_4_auto_rotate mMSimDataDirectionIconId=0x0 mMSimDataSignalIconId=0x7f020293 mMSimDataTypeIconId=0x0/(null) mNoMSimIconId=0x7f020088/com.android.systemui:drawable/ic_qs_no_sim mMSimMobileActivityIconId=0x0/(null) mWifiIconId=0x7f0202d4 mBluetoothTetherIconId=0x7f0202b2 mRoamingIconId=0x 0/(null) mSimEnabled=true
02-09 11:38:55.196 3214-3214/? D/StatusBar.MSimNetworkController: getUpdateDataNetType(): 0
02-09 11:38:55.196 3214-3214/? D/StatusBar.MSimNetworkController: updateDataNetType sub = 1 mDataNetType = 0
02-09 11:38:55.196 3214-3214/? E/StatusBar.MSimNetworkController: updateDataNetType NETWORK_TYPE_UNKNOWN
02-09 11:38:55.196 3214-3214/? D/StatusBar.MSimNetworkController: NoService, mRoamingIconId = 0phoneId : 1
02-09 11:38:55.196 3214-3214/? D/StatusBar.MSimNetworkController: isSIMOFFOfSlot simDBvalue0 = 1, simDBvalue1 =1
02-09 11:38:55.196 3214-3214/? D/StatusBar.MSimNetworkController: updateZTMDataNetType()
02-09 11:38:55.196 3214-3214/? D/StatusBar.MSimNetworkController: updateDataIcon mDataNetType= 0
02-09 11:38:55.206 2839-3131/? D/WifiNetworkAgent: NetworkAgent: NetworkAgent channel lost
02-09 11:38:55.206 2839-3131/? E/WifiStateMachine: Error! unhandled message{ when=-19ms what=135188 target=com.android.internal.util.StateMachine$SmHandler }
02-09 11:38:55.206 2839-3131/? E/WifiStateMachine: Error! unhandled message{ when=-19ms what=135188 target=com.android.internal.util.StateMachine$SmHandler }
02-09 11:38:55.206 3214-3214/? D/StatusBar.MSimNetworkController: updateDataIcon phoneId =1 dataSub =0
02-09 11:38:55.206 3214-3214/? D/StatusBar.MSimNetworkController: updateDataIcon( 1 )  GSM :  mMSimState= ABSENT mDataNetType= 0
02-09 11:38:55.206 3214-3214/? D/StatusBar.MSimNetworkController: updateDataIcon no sim
02-09 11:38:55.206 3214-3214/? D/StatusBar.MSimNetworkController: updateDataIcon when mMSimDataConnected[1] =false mMSimMobileActivityIconId[1] = 0
02-09 11:38:55.216 2839-3131/? E/WifiStateMachine: Error! unhandled message{ when=-24ms what=135188 target=com.android.internal.util.StateMachine$SmHandler }
02-09 11:38:55.216 2839-3131/? D/SecContentProvider2: uri = 20 selection = getPromptCredentialsEnabled
02-09 11:38:55.216 2839-3131/? D/SecContentProvider2: mCursor = null
02-09 11:38:55.216 3214-3214/? D/StatusBar.MSimNetworkController: refreshViews connected={ wifi } phoneId = 1 level=0 mMSimcombinedSignalIconId=0x7f0202d4/com.android.systemui:drawable/stat_sys_wifi_signal_4 mMSimcombinedActivityIconId=0x7f0202a8 mAirplaneMode=false mMSimDataActivity=0 mMSimPhoneSignalIconId=0x7f020389/com.android.systemui:drawable/tw_stat_sys_signal_null mMSimDataDirectionIconId=0x0 mMSimDataSignalIconId=0x7f020389 mMSimDataTypeIconId=0x0/(null) mNoMSimIconId=0x7f020088/com.android.systemui:drawable/ic_qs_no_sim mMSimMobileActivityIconId=0x0/(null) mWifiIconId=0x7f0202d4 mBluetoothTetherIconId=0x7f0202b2 mRoamingIconId=0x 0/(null) mSimEnabled=false
02-09 11:38:55.216 3214-3214/? D/STATUSBAR-WifiQuickSettingButton: onWifiSignalChanged enabled=true enabledDesc:"INACLIVE 2"
02-09 11:38:55.216 3214-3214/? D/StatusBar.MSimNetworkController: getUpdateDataNetType(): 0
02-09 11:38:55.216 2839-19244/? D/ActivityManager: startService callerProcessName:com.whatsapp, calleePkgName: com.whatsapp
02-09 11:38:55.216 28448-28770/br.tv.inaclive.qridpresenca I/System.out: pool-2-thread-2 calls detatch()
02-09 11:38:55.216 32697-32697/? I/SAMP: ActivityThread() - SAMP_ENABLE : true
02-09 11:38:55.216 3214-3214/? D/StatusBar.MSimNetworkController: updateDataNetType sub = 0 mDataNetType = 0
02-09 11:38:55.216 3214-3214/? E/StatusBar.MSimNetworkController: updateDataNetType NETWORK_TYPE_UNKNOWN
02-09 11:38:55.216 28448-28770/br.tv.inaclive.qridpresenca W/System.err: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://beacon.qrid.com.br refused
02-09 11:38:55.226 28448-28770/br.tv.inaclive.qridpresenca W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:241)
02-09 11:38:55.226 28448-28770/br.tv.inaclive.qridpresenca W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:172)
02-09 11:38:55.226 3214-3214/? D/StatusBar.MSimNetworkController: Nothing final, mRoamingIconId = 0 phoneId : 0
02-09 11:38:55.226 3214-3214/? D/StatusBar.MSimNetworkController: updateZTMDataNetType()
02-09 11:38:55.226 3214-3214/? D/StatusBar.MSimNetworkController: updateDataIcon mDataNetType= 0
02-09 11:38:55.226 28448-28770/br.tv.inaclive.qridpresenca W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:130)
02-09 11:38:55.226 28448-28770/br.tv.inaclive.qridpresenca W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.executeOriginal(DefaultRequestDirector.java:1317)
02-09 11:38:55.226 28448-28770/br.tv.inaclive.qridpresenca W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:707)
02-09 11:38:55.226 28448-28770/br.tv.inaclive.qridpresenca W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:696)
02-09 11:38:55.226 28448-28770/br.tv.inaclive.qridpresenca W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:519)
02-09 11:38:55.226 28448-28770/br.tv.inaclive.qridpresenca W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:497)
02-09 11:38:55.236 2414-2900/? D/EnterpriseController: mIsMarkChainAdded is 0 mIsBlockChainAdded is 0 netId is 0
02-09 11:38:55.236 2414-2900/? D/Netd: getNetworkForDns: using netid 0 for uid 1000
02-09 11:38:55.236 2839-3134/? D/ConnectivityService: setProvNotificationVisibleIntent: E visible=false networkType=1 extraInfo=null
02-09 11:38:55.236 2839-29229/? D/NetworkMonitor/NetworkAgentInfo [WIFI () - 512]: Probably not a portal: exception java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "connectivitycheck.android.com": No address associated with hostname
02-09 11:38:55.236 2839-29229/? D/NetworkMonitor/NetworkAgentInfo [WIFI () - 512]: Validated
02-09 11:38:55.236 2839-3134/? V/NetworkStats: updateIfacesLocked()
02-09 11:38:55.236 2839-3134/? V/NetworkStats: performPollLocked(flags=0x1)
02-09 11:38:55.236 2839-3134/? D/NetworkStatsFactory: UpdateStatsForKnox updated
02-09 11:38:55.236 2839-3134/? D/NetworkStatsFactory: UpdateStatsForKnox main else ---
02-09 11:38:55.246 2839-3134/? V/NetworkStats: performPollLocked() took 5ms
02-09 11:38:55.266 3214-3214/? D/StatusBar.MSimNetworkController: updateDataIcon phoneId =0 dataSub =0
02-09 11:38:55.266 3214-3214/? D/StatusBar.MSimNetworkController: updateDataIcon( 0 )  GSM :  mMSimState= ABSENT mDataNetType= 0
02-09 11:38:55.266 3214-3214/? D/StatusBar.MSimNetworkController: updateDataIcon no sim
02-09 11:38:55.276 2839-3212/? V/BroadcastQueue: [background] Process cur broadcast BroadcastRecord{393e1eb4 u0 com.samsung.android.net.wifi.SHOW_NOTI_MESSAGE} DELIVERED for app ProcessRecord{61add 32697:com.android.settings/1000}
02-09 11:38:55.276 3214-3214/? D/StatusBar.MSimNetworkController: updateDataIcon when mMSimDataConnected[0] =false mMSimMobileActivityIconId[0] = 0
02-09 11:38:55.276 2839-3134/? D/ConnectivityService: getAllNetworkState networkCapability  = [ Transports: WIFI Capabilities: WIFI_P2P&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED&NOT_VPN LinkUpBandwidth>=1048576Kbps LinkDnBandwidth>=1048576Kbps]
02-09 11:38:55.276 2839-3134/? D/ConnectivityService: getAllNetworkState networkCapability  = [ Transports: WIFI Capabilities: INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED&NOT_VPN LinkUpBandwidth>=1048576Kbps LinkDnBandwidth>=1048576Kbps]
02-09 11:38:55.276 2839-3134/? D/ConnectivityService: notifyType LOST for NetworkAgentInfo [WIFI () - 512]
02-09 11:38:55.276 2839-29229/? D/NetworkMonitor/NetworkAgentInfo [WIFI () - 512]: ValidatedState{ when=0 what=532487 target=com.android.internal.util.StateMachine$SmHandler }
02-09 11:38:55.276 2839-3134/? D/ConnectivityService: Checking for replacement network to handle request NetworkRequest [ id=1, legacyType=-1, [ Capabilities: INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED&NOT_VPN] ]
02-09 11:38:55.276 2839-3130/? D/WIFI_P2P: evalRequest evalRequest  = NetworkRequest [ id=1, legacyType=-1, [ Capabilities: INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED&NOT_VPN] ] n.requested= false
02-09 11:38:55.276 2839-3134/? D/CSLegacyTypeTracker: Removing agent NetworkAgentInfo{ ni{[type: WIFI[] - WIFI, state: DISCONNECTED/DISCONNECTED, reason: (unspecified), extra: , roaming: false, failover: false, isAvailable: true, isConnectedToProvisioningNetwork: false]}  network{512}  lp{{InterfaceName: wlan0 LinkAddresses: [192.168.0.104/24,fe80::2255:31ff:fe67:b8c8/64,]  Routes: [fe80::/64 -> :: wlan0,192.168.0.0/24 -> 0.0.0.0 wlan0,0.0.0.0/0 -> 192.168.0.1 wlan0,] DnsAddresses: [8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4,] Domains:  MTU: 0 TcpBufferSizes: 524288,1048576,4525824,524288,1048576,4525824}}  nc{[ Transports: WIFI Capabilities: INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED&NOT_VPN LinkUpBandwidth>=1048576Kbps LinkDnBandwidth>=1048576Kbps]}  Score{60}  everValidated{true}  lastValidated{true}  created{true}  explicitlySelected{false} }
02-09 11:38:55.276 2839-3134/? D/CSLegacyTypeTracker: Sending disconnected broadcast for type 1 NetworkAgentInfo [WIFI () - 512] isDefaultNetwork=false
02-09 11:38:55.276 2839-3134/? D/ConnectivityService: sendStickyBroadcast: action=android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE_IMMEDIATE
02-09 11:38:55.276 2839-3131/? D/WIFI: evalRequest evalRequest  = NetworkRequest [ id=1, legacyType=-1, [ Capabilities: INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED&NOT_VPN] ] n.requested= true
02-09 11:38:55.286 3214-3214/? D/StatusBar.MSimNetworkController: Nothing final, mRoamingIconId = 0 phoneId : 0
02-09 11:38:55.286 3214-3214/? D/StatusBar.MSimNetworkController: refreshViews connected={ } phoneId = 0 level=4 mMSimcombinedSignalIconId=0x7f020293/com.android.systemui:drawable/stat_sys_signal_4_auto_rotate mMSimcombinedActivityIconId=0x0 mAirplaneMode=false mMSimDataActivity=0 mMSimPhoneSignalIconId=0x7f020293/com.android.systemui:drawable/stat_sys_signal_4_auto_rotate mMSimDataDirectionIconId=0x0 mMSimDataSignalIconId=0x7f020293 mMSimDataTypeIconId=0x0/(null) mNoMSimIconId=0x7f020088/com.android.systemui:drawable/ic_qs_no_sim mMSimMobileActivityIconId=0x0/(null) mWifiIconId=0x7f0202c8 mBluetoothTetherIconId=0x7f0202b2 mRoamingIconId=0x 0/(null) mSimEnabled=true
02-09 11:38:55.286 3214-3214/? D/STATUSBAR-WifiQuickSettingButton: onWifiSignalChanged enabled=true enabledDesc:null
02-09 11:38:55.286 2839-3134/? D/ConnectivityService: sendStickyBroadcast: action=android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE
02-09 11:38:55.286 3214-3586/? D/ConnectivityManager.CallbackHandler: CM callback handler got msg 524292
02-09 11:38:55.286 3214-3214/? D/StatusBar.MSimNetworkController: refreshSignalCluster : called
02-09 11:38:55.286 2839-2934/? D/EntConnectivity: Not allowed due to - mEnabled false
02-09 11:38:55.286 2839-2839/? D/Tethering: Tethering got CONNECTIVITY_ACTION_IMMEDIATE
02-09 11:38:55.286 2839-3135/? D/Tethering: MasterInitialState.processMessage what=3
02-09 11:38:55.286 2839-3134/? D/ConnectivityService: setProvNotificationVisibleIntent: E visible=false networkType=0 extraInfo=null
02-09 11:38:55.286 2839-3134/? D/ConnectivityService: nai.networkMonitor.doQuit()
02-09 11:38:55.286 2839-3134/? D/NetworkMonitor/NetworkAgentInfo [WIFI () - 512]: doQuit - quitNow()
02-09 11:38:55.296 32697-32697/? W/ResourcesManager: getTopLevelResources: null for user  0
02-09 11:38:55.296 2839-2934/? D/EntConnectivity: Not allowed due to - mEnabled false
02-09 11:38:55.296 3214-3214/? E/StatusBar.MSimNetworkController: Error : mSimIconId is -1
02-09 11:38:55.316 2839-3129/? D/ConnectivityService: getAllNetworkState networkCapability  = [ Transports: WIFI Capabilities: WIFI_P2P&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED&NOT_VPN LinkUpBandwidth>=1048576Kbps LinkDnBandwidth>=1048576Kbps]
02-09 11:38:55.316 3214-3214/? E/StatusBar.MSimNetworkController: Error : mSimIconId is -1
02-09 11:38:55.316 3214-3214/? D/StatusBar.MSimNetworkController: getUpdateDataNetType(): 0
02-09 11:38:55.316 2839-3129/? V/NetworkStats: advisePersistThreshold() given 9223372036854775, clamped to 2097152
02-09 11:38:55.326 3214-3214/? D/StatusBar.MSimNetworkController: NoService, mRoamingIconId = 0phoneId : 1
02-09 11:38:55.326 3214-3214/? D/StatusBar.MSimNetworkController: updateDataNetType sub = 1 mDataNetType = 0
02-09 11:38:55.326 3214-3214/? E/StatusBar.MSimNetworkController: updateDataNetType NETWORK_TYPE_UNKNOWN
02-09 11:38:55.326 3214-3214/? D/StatusBar.MSimNetworkController: isSIMOFFOfSlot simDBvalue0 = 1, simDBvalue1 =1
02-09 11:38:55.326 3214-3214/? D/StatusBar.MSimNetworkController: updateZTMDataNetType()
02-09 11:38:55.326 3214-3214/? D/StatusBar.MSimNetworkController: updateDataIcon mDataNetType= 0
02-09 11:38:55.326 3214-3214/? D/StatusBar.MSimNetworkController: updateDataIcon phoneId =1 dataSub =0
02-09 11:38:55.326 3214-3214/? D/StatusBar.MSimNetworkController: updateDataIcon( 1 )  GSM :  mMSimState= ABSENT mDataNetType= 0
02-09 11:38:55.326 3214-3214/? D/StatusBar.MSimNetworkController: updateDataIcon no sim
02-09 11:38:55.326 3214-3214/? D/StatusBar.MSimNetworkController: updateDataIcon when mMSimDataConnected[1] =false mMSimMobileActivityIconId[1] = 0
02-09 11:38:55.336 3214-3214/? D/StatusBar.MSimNetworkController: NoService, mRoamingIconId = 0phoneId : 1
02-09 11:38:55.336 3214-3214/? D/StatusBar.MSimNetworkController: isSIMOFFOfSlot simDBvalue0 = 1, simDBvalue1 =1
02-09 11:38:55.336 3214-3214/? D/STATUSBAR-WifiQuickSettingButton: onWifiSignalChanged enabled=true enabledDesc:null
02-09 11:38:55.336 3214-3214/? D/StatusBar.MSimNetworkController: refreshViews connected={ } phoneId = 1 level=0 mMSimcombinedSignalIconId=0x7f020389/com.android.systemui:drawable/tw_stat_sys_signal_null mMSimcombinedActivityIconId=0x0 mAirplaneMode=false mMSimDataActivity=0 mMSimPhoneSignalIconId=0x7f020389/com.android.systemui:drawable/tw_stat_sys_signal_null mMSimDataDirectionIconId=0x0 mMSimDataSignalIconId=0x7f020389 mMSimDataTypeIconId=0x0/(null) mNoMSimIconId=0x7f020088/com.android.systemui:drawable/ic_qs_no_sim mMSimMobileActivityIconId=0x0/(null) mWifiIconId=0x7f0202c8 mBluetoothTetherIconId=0x7f0202b2 mRoamingIconId=0x 0/(null) mSimEnabled=false
02-09 11:38:55.336 32697-32697/? W/ResourcesManager: Asset path '/system/framework/sec_platform_library.jar' does not exist or contains no resources.
02-09 11:38:55.336 32697-32697/? W/ResourcesManager: Asset path '/system/framework/com.google.android.maps.jar' does not exist or contains no resources.
02-09 11:38:55.336 3214-3214/? D/StatusBar.MSimNetworkController: updateConnectivity: intent=Intent { act=android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE_IMMEDIATE flg=0x4000010 (has extras) }
02-09 11:38:55.336 32697-32697/? W/ResourcesManager: Asset path '/system/framework/twframework.jar' does not exist or contains no resources.
02-09 11:38:55.336 32697-32697/? W/ResourcesManager: Asset path '/system/framework/com.broadcom.bt.jar' does not exist or contains no resources.
02-09 11:38:55.336 3214-3214/? D/StatusBar.MSimNetworkController: getUpdateDataNetType(): 0
02-09 11:38:55.336 3214-3214/? D/StatusBar.MSimNetworkController: updateConnectivity: networkInfo=null
02-09 11:38:55.336 3214-3214/? D/StatusBar.MSimNetworkController: updateConnectivity: connectionStatus=0
02-09 11:38:55.346 3214-3214/? D/StatusBar.MSimNetworkController: updateDataNetType sub = 0 mDataNetType = 0
02-09 11:38:55.346 3214-3214/? E/StatusBar.MSimNetworkController: updateDataNetType NETWORK_TYPE_UNKNOWN
02-09 11:38:55.346 3214-3214/? D/StatusBar.MSimNetworkController: Nothing final, mRoamingIconId = 0 phoneId : 0
02-09 11:38:55.346 3214-3214/? D/StatusBar.MSimNetworkController: updateZTMDataNetType()
02-09 11:38:55.356 3214-3214/? D/StatusBar.MSimNetworkController: updateDataIcon mDataNetType= 0
02-09 11:38:55.356 3214-3214/? D/StatusBar.MSimNetworkController: updateDataIcon phoneId =0 dataSub =0
02-09 11:38:55.356 3214-3214/? D/StatusBar.MSimNetworkController: updateDataIcon( 0 )  GSM :  mMSimState= ABSENT mDataNetType= 0
02-09 11:38:55.356 3214-3214/? D/StatusBar.MSimNetworkController: updateDataIcon no sim
02-09 11:38:55.356 3214-3214/? D/StatusBar.MSimNetworkController: updateDataIcon when mMSimDataConnected[0] =false mMSimMobileActivityIconId[0] = 0
02-09 11:38:55.356 3214-3214/? D/StatusBar.MSimNetworkController: updateTelephonySignalStrength: phoneId =0
02-09 11:38:55.356 3214-3214/? D/StatusBar.MSimNetworkController: getNumberOfActiveSim:1
02-09 11:38:55.356 3214-3214/? D/StatusBar.MSimNetworkController: updateTelephonySignalStrength iconLevel = 4 mInetCondition = 0
02-09 11:38:55.356 3214-3214/? D/StatusBar.MSimNetworkController: getPhoneSignalIconList: mMaxLevelOfSignalStrengthIndicator = 4 inetCondition = 0
02-09 11:38:55.356 3214-3214/? D/StatusBar.MSimNetworkController: updateTelephonySignalStrength: iconLevel=4
02-09 11:38:55.356 3214-3214/? D/StatusBar.MSimNetworkController: getUpdateDataNetType(): 0
02-09 11:38:55.366 3214-3214/? D/StatusBar.MSimNetworkController: NoService, mRoamingIconId = 0phoneId : 1
02-09 11:38:55.366 3214-3214/? D/StatusBar.MSimNetworkController: updateDataNetType sub = 1 mDataNetType = 0
02-09 11:38:55.366 3214-3214/? E/StatusBar.MSimNetworkController: updateDataNetType NETWORK_TYPE_UNKNOWN
02-09 11:38:55.366 3214-3214/? D/StatusBar.MSimNetworkController: isSIMOFFOfSlot simDBvalue0 = 1, simDBvalue1 =1
02-09 11:38:55.366 3214-3214/? D/StatusBar.MSimNetworkController: updateZTMDataNetType()

Comment: How about giving a static IP to your device-wifi, instead of the default one assigned by DHCP, also try this [app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.macdom.ble.blescanner "tttttt").

Answer (score 0):

Well since BLE and WiFi shares the same radio, and the only scan parameters you can use in KitKat is 100% duty, it's not that strange you see decreased WiFi performance. Try a newer phone which might have a smarter scheduler that divides BLE time and WiFi time for the radio better. With Lollipop and forward you can also change the scan window to a more restrictive one with the new BluetoothLeScanner API (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/ScanSettings.html#SCAN_MODE_LOW_POWER).

Comment: "This is the default scan mode as it consumes the least power." 

And I'm testing in Android 5+ already. But thanks the answer